# javascript keeps skipping my if statement thats inside two loops

Tags: javascript, if-statement, nested-loops

Ok so im talking in some unput from the user, it must be 4 numbers, and the digits must not be the same. so everything is working accept the part where i check the 4 numbers against each other. i put the string into an array and then compare the array, by 
checking the first one against the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 
then i check the second one against the 3rd, and 4th 
then i check the third number against the 4th

My issue is the if statement will not work no matter what i try it gets bypassed everytime. I add random returns into the code to see where it goes and it always returns 12 no matter what even if the numbers i enter are 1111 it still passes.

Ive spent hours trying different stuff please help me!!

```
function validate(guess){

var user_guess = guess;
var valid = true;
var counter = 0;

parseFloat(user_guess);

if(user_guess.length == 4){

    if((user_guess == null) || (isNaN(user_guess))){

        validation_alert();

    }else{

        var guess_string = toString(user_guess);
        var guess_array = guess_string.split('');
        var guess_array2 = guess_array;

        for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){

            counter = i + 1;

            for(c = counter; c < 4; c++){

                if(guess_array[i] == guess_array2[c]){

                    return 11;
                    valid = false;
                    validation_alert();

                }

            }

        }

        if(valid == true){

        return 12;

        }else{

            return 13;
            validation_alert();

        }

    }//if null


}else{

    validation_alert();

}//if 4 end tag



}// function close
```

Comment: First thing I notice is 'counter = i + 1' but you also declare 'i++' inside your first for loop. Also the validation doesn't make much sense, if you're validating out NaN, then you also 'guess_string.split('')', what do you need the value to be? A number or a string?

Comment: im trying to have the second loop always start 1 position in the array ahead of the other so on the first iteration of the second loop they dont compare the same value. i do nan first to see if what was entered was strictly a number, then i turn it back into a string in order to take each digit and put them into an array .split only seemed to work with strings

Comment: Try utilizing your browsers javascript debug tools. Set break points at the parts where you think the for loop should be hitting, and see if you make it to the loop.

Comment: i did this and when it does toString it makes the variable equal to object window? what the heck is that

Comment: Instead of using `toString()` you can also just do `1111 + ''`

Answer (score 1):

Just to prove to you that JavaScript uses function scope and not block scope (`if else for ...`) which means every `var` you declare moves automatically to the top of the current function it's running in.

Also note that when you `return` something you will exit the current function and not execute anything after that.

If you check against `length` you can be sure it's going to be a number so use `===` instead which checks against it's type (number, string, bool) as well.

Your 2 first `if` statements should be reversed I think. In anycase `user_guess == null` will never validate as the previous `if` checks on the `length === 4`.

Normally when you use `return` every block scope should return something. I haven't edited this but that's expected in strict javascript.

It seems more logical to start with `valid=false` and you will only set it to true when you are sure it's true. I'll leave that up to you.

```
function validate(guess){
    var user_guess = parseFloat(guess),
        guess_string,
        guess_array,
        guess_array2,
        valid = true,
        counter = 0,
        i = 0,
        c;

    if (!user_guess || isNaN(user_guess)){
        validation_alert();
    } else {
        if (guess.length === 4){
            guess_string = user_guess.toString();
            guess_array = guess_string.split('');
            guess_array2 = guess_array;

            for (i; i < 3; i++){
                counter = i + 1;
                c = counter;
                for (c; c < 4; c++){
                    if (guess_array[i] == guess_array2[c]){
                        valid = false;
                        validation_alert();
                        return 11;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (valid){
                return 12;
            } else {
                validation_alert();
                return 13;

            }
        } else {
            validation_alert();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: am i going about this in a really dumb way? is this to much just to see if the array doesnt reapeat any digits? also when i went into debugger with my code the array equaled object window split into characters? where did that even come from

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to check if the string has 4 unique number digits its much easier this way:

```
function isValid(str){
    var unique={};
    for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){//for each character in the string
        unique[str[i]]=true;//we add the character as a key in unique object(the =true doesnt really matter)
    }
    var chars=Object.keys(unique);//we get an array with the keys in the object(we get an array with the unique characters)
    if(chars.length != 4) return false; //if the unique chracters are different than 4, its not valid so return false
    chars.sort();//we order the array in lexicographical order
    if(chars[0]>= '0' && chars[0] <='9' && chars[3]>= '0' && chars[3] <='9') return true;//if the first character and the last ones are digits, then the ones in the middle wil be digits as well because of the sort we made. If they are, return true
    return false;//if they are not both digits, return false
}
console.log(isValid('1111'))//false
console.log(isValid('9230'))//true
console.log(isValid('1343'))//false
console.log(isValid('a412'))//false
console.log(isValid(''))//false
```

Comment: im too stupid to understand what is going on in this code but thanks for showing me something much shorter!

Comment: Just commented each line, hope you understand @user2827925!